# Regex return no matches if lookahead matches

Tags: ruby, regex

I am attempting to find child paths of a UNIX style path using regex, I take three parameters:

- `root` the directory to compare against.
- `minDepth` the minimum amount of levels down required.
- `maxDepth` the maximum amount of levels down to match against.

I have created the following function (`@items` is defined elsewhere):

```
module Navigation
  def dig (root = nil, minDepth = 1, maxDepth = nil)
    root ||= "/"
    @items.select{ |i| !(i.path =~ %r{"\A#{root}(.*?/){#{minDepth},#{maxDepth}}"}).nil? }
  end
end
```

My issue is with getting the regex to obey `maxDepth`, currently the regex finds a match even if there are more levels in the path it is just not included in the match. For example:

The path `/foo/bar/daz/bag/cop/fig/leg` gets matched by the regex `%r{\A/foo(.*?/){1,3}}` although only the `/foo/bar/daz/` matches. How would I modify my regex to not match if there is a forward slash at any point after the match?

So that: `/foo/bar/daz/hey` would have a match but `/foo/bar/daz/hey/` would not.

I've attempted to use negative lookaheads but am not being very successful, it is likely I am not utilising them correctly.

Comment: Are you searching a document for multiple paths or would the full string contain only one path?

Comment: @tenub each `@items` element contains a single path string. I am extending an environment that fills `@items` and don't control it's contents.

Comment: Also, what is your end goal here? Are you trying to find all paths that match a certain range? Ie. in your example, paths between 1 and 3 directories deep?

Comment: @tenub yes, if `maxDepth` is nil it should match any depth otherwise be limited to that range. Hence why I need to lookahead and fail the match if there are slashes ahead of the match.

Comment: @GeorgeReith How did you use the negative look ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this work?

```
\A/foo(/[^/]*?){1,3}\Z


module Navigation
  def dig (root = nil, minDepth = 1, maxDepth = nil)
    root ||= "/"
    @items.select{ |i| !(i.path =~ %r{"\A#{root}(/[^/]*?){#{minDepth},#{maxDepth}}\Z"}).nil? }
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to work... although I don't get what the start of line character does here. Could you explain?

Comment: [^/] means: match any character that is NOT a '/' (if it is what you are asking for)

Comment: Ah I see... that is much a better way of doing it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Just a note to anyone else who wants to use this... `root` needs to be an empty string instead of `"\"` in case of the top level.